# Min and max validation

Tags: angularjs

I have two inputs one for min and the other for max value. 
How can I add validation so the min < max?

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Montant minimum</label> 
    <input id="min" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="type.minMontant" required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Montant maximum</label> 
    <input id="max" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="type.maxMontant" required/>
</div>
```

And then when I'll try to pick a value, it must be in [min,max] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not Sure if this is wat you want**

**if you want validation messages to show then you have to use angular-messages**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Montant minimum</label> 
        <input id="min" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" max="{{maxMontant}}" ng-model="minMontant" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Montant maximum</label> 
        <input id="max" class="form-control" type="number" max="10" ng-model="maxMontant" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `min` and `max` attiribute(html5)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Montant minimum</label> 
    <input id="min" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="type.minMontant" min="0" required/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Montant maximum</label> 
    <input id="max" class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="type.maxMontant" max="10" required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have custom validators to check integrity of range and then check the input value with available range.

Following is a simulation of it:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/guumuvn1/1/)

```js
$scope.validate = function() {
  var valid = $scope.validateMin() && $scope.validateMax();
  if (valid) {
    if ($scope.type.value >= $scope.type.min &&
      $scope.type.value <= $scope.type.max) {
      alert("Correct Value")
    } else {
      alert("Out of range");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Incorrent range values entered");
  }
}
```